# Preencher ProgressBar em JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

estou vendo JavaFX, estou com duvidas no uso de ProgressBar. Como faço para Preencher o ProgressBar enquanto ocorre outra operação paralela.?

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo de como preencher um `ProgressBar`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @author Felipe
 */
public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ProgressBar barra = new ProgressBar();
        Button btn = new Button("Carregar");
        Label status = new Label("Novo");

        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent acao) -> {
            //criando um classe anônima Service que cria uma Task que também é anônima
            //a classe Service serve para gerenciar threads em JavaFX 
            Service<Void> servico = new Service() {
                @Override
                protected Task createTask() {
                    return new Task() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void call() throws Exception {
                            //Task tem duas property interessantes para usar junto a um ProgressBar
                            //a messageProperty, que pode ser ligada a outra StringProperty
                            //para transmitir uma mensagem,
                            //e a progressProperty, que serve para mandar valores númericos a uma
                            //ProgressBar ou ProgressIndicator
                            updateMessage("Carregando...");
                            Thread.sleep(300);
                            updateProgress(1, 10);
                            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                                updateProgress(i + 1, 10);
                                updateMessage("Carregando " + (i + 1) + " de 10");
                                Thread.sleep(300);
                            }
                            updateMessage("Terminou");
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
            //fazendo o bind (ligando) nas proprety
            status.textProperty().bind(servico.messageProperty());
            barra.progressProperty().bind(servico.progressProperty());
            //precisa inicializar o Service
            servico.restart();
        });

        //criando um ui para exemplificar o uso do ProgressBar
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(status, btn, barra);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 150, 150);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Progress Bar!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```